# What is Jooq Transaction isolation level? Can dirty read happen?

Tags: mysql, transactions, jooq

Based on comments in https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.6/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/ changing isolation level doesn't seems possible with Jooq yet. However it is not clear what is the isolation level Jooq is setting, hence my question: **what is the isolation level that Jooq is using?**

Especially, it looks like I am experiencing dirty reads, while I need the transaction to prevent that. **Can someone confirm that dirty reads are prevented by Jooq transactions?**

*Note: Using Jooq with Mysql. The DB is an AWS Aurora instance.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ 3.9 doesn't support managing transaction isolation levels yet. The relevant feature request to add support for this is [#4836](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4836).

You will need to configure your JDBC connection directly, or indirectly via your connection pool / data source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what I thought. Even if Jooq doesn't let users set a specific isolation level, it should however be passing some isolation level to jdbc or to mysql, right? I was wondering which one that would be.

Comment: @Pierre: By default, the isolation level is more of a server-side and/or JDBC setting. jOOQ would inherit it.

Comment: postgres allows setting isolation level at beginning of transaction. any reason not to support that? is that unique to postgres?

Comment: @pdeva: You can implement a `TransactionListener` in jOOQ, I suspect. There is no reason "not to support that" other than, this is a complex topic and needs careful and thorough thought and testing across 25 supported RDBMS, and is currently out of scope.

Comment: @LukasEder i did not know about the `TransactionListener`. is there any documentation/example of how to use it to set isolation?

Comment: @pdeva. No, there currently isn't.