# How to specify transaction isolation in JOOQ transactions?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

when creating sql transactions using JOOQ how does one specify isolation level for the transaction, eg ReadCommitted or Serializable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577945/what-is-jooq-transaction-isolation-level-can-dirty-read-happen